# Split '&lt; &gt;' line with python re

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I cannot figure out how to split this line with &lt, &gt symbols:

```
"&lt;c#&gt;&lt;winforms&gt;&lt;type-conversion&gt;&lt;decimal&gt;&lt;opacity&gt;"
```

I would like to get following list from the line above:

```
['c#', 'winforms', 'type-conversion', 'decimal', 'opacity']
```

What I tried so far is re.split, but got no luck:

```
>>> re.split("&lt;(\w+?)&gt;", "&lt;c#&gt;&lt;winforms&gt;&lt;type-conversion&gt;&lt;decimal&gt;&lt;opacity&gt;")

['&lt;c#&gt;', 'winforms', '&lt;type-conversion&gt;', 'decimal', '', 'opacity', '']
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If we a few assumptions about the input string are true, we can probably avoid regular expressions all together.  My assumptions is that the "columns" are xml escaped strings that follow this form:  `<col1><col2>...<coln>`.  If that is the case, then we really don't need the `<` (so lets remove it) and we can split on `>`.

```
>>> s = "&lt;c#&gt;&lt;winforms&gt;&lt;type-conversion&gt;&lt;decimal&gt;&lt;opacity&gt;"
>>> s.replace('&lt;', '').split('&gt;')
['c#', 'winforms', 'type-conversion', 'decimal', 'opacity', '']
```

This leaves exactly one empty string at the end of the list, but that's easy enough to slice off or handle by just skipping during processing.

Comment: Doing stuff like this without `import` always restores hope in *string literal* methods as opposed to `re`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye -- Yeah.  Regular expressions are fantastic and _super_ useful.  I think that almost every programmer should know at least basic regular expressions.  With that said, I think that other options should frequently be explored before reaching for regular expressions since they're so hard to understand a few hours after you've written them...

Comment: Exactly! `regex` is so powerful, it can't kill a fly *decently*

Answer (score 1):

`split()` or `re.split()` based solutions should probably be preferred in this case, but here is an alternative "don't use it in practice" approach involving using HTML parsers:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
>>>
>>> s = "&lt;c#&gt;&lt;winforms&gt;&lt;type-conversion&gt;&lt;decimal&gt;&lt;opacity&gt;"
>>> [tag.name for tag in BeautifulSoup(HTMLParser().unescape(s), "html.parser").find_all()]
[u'c#', u'winforms', u'type-conversion', u'decimal', u'opacity']
```

Comment: @mgilson yeah, and I could not resist the temptation to try out HTML-parsing approach after seeing so terribly familiar `&lt;` and `&gt;` :)

Comment: Yep, that was my thinking too.  I abandoned that approach because there weren't any closing tags, but apparently `BeautifulSoup` doesn't care.  I'll have to try to remember that.

Answer (score 1):

Why use split, it just uses a regex for start/end cut'n paste.
Cut out the middle man, it's quicker.

Use a findall kind of function with a regex like this
(set the *dot-all* modifier if spanning lines)

`((?:(?!&[gl]t;).)+)(?:&[gl]t;)*`

Or, if you still need to use split use this regex

`(?:&[gl]t;)+`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
[s for s in re.split("&lt;|&gt;", str) if s]
```

which returns:

```
'c#', 'winforms', 'type-conversion', 'decimal', 'opacity']
```